# Cannot use project as a library reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms Application called ProfileManager. Inside this application, I have classes with namespaces ProfileManager.Entity, ProfileManager.DAL, etc.

I am referencing the dll of this project from another ASP.NET Web Forms Application.

In the code of the second application, I am writing lines like this

```
using ProfileManager.Entity;
using ProfileManager.DAL;
```

But Visual Studio are giving the following error for the above lines

***The type or namespace name 'ProfileManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?***

I am attaching screenshots to explain.

[image]

[image]

I changed the name of my ProfileManager project and also all the namespaces to ProfileManagerLibrary. But still I get the same error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are referencing it from another app. So you solved this "problem" before.

Comment: I do not understand ... this is the first time I am using the reference of my ProfileManager project in another application

Comment: What type of web application is this? Is it one where your classes are all under an `App_Code` folder? If so, those aren't compiled until the app starts and so they're not usable from other projects.

Comment: My classes are **not** in the AppCode folder

Comment: I have added screenshots to better explain the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile ProfileManager as a type of Library, not as a type of application.  Compiling it as an ASP.NET Web Application means it can only be run from a webserver, and cannot be used as a library reference.